# What's the fastest way to cook fluffy white Jasmine rice?

Tags: rice

From raw grains until ready to eat, what's the fastest method you can think of to get fluffy white rice (Thai Jasmine variety).

I've tried using a pressure cooker and it's pretty fast, but there's the initial heat up time needed to reach high pressure and then the depressurization time after cooking.

I've been able to get fluffy white rice within 12 mins in an electric pressure cooker, including depressurization, but this is still a little to slow.

Any ideas?  I'm trying to reach 5-6 mins total, from the moment I apply heat to when I start eating.

Comment: That's not a lot of time to allow the grains to hydrate properly.  Even 12 minutes is pretty ridiculously fast if you ask me.  Why such a tight time constraint?  Is pre-cooking a large batch and re-heating not an option for some reason?

Comment: To add to logophobe's comment, you could make your rice in a big batch, cool enough to handle, then put it in Ziplocks and freeze. Works great.

Comment: Hi @logophobe, I'm trying to build a rice cooker that can cook rice in 5-6 minutes, to compete with the microwave speeds, which is why I have the time constraint.

Answer (score 0):

for one cup of rice :

Rinse the rice and soak it for couples of minutes .

once u set the rice to soak boil three cups of water in a pan.

once water starts boiling, add a bit of drop of oil and add the rice(drained) and stir well.

Rice should be done in 3- 4 minutes. Check it with a spoon.

once done drain it and rinse it under cold water and microwave it for a minute (this is to make the rice fluffy and warm).

The entire process takes about 8- 10 minutes  and its a healthy option.

Hope this helps ! but sry I haven't tired it for 6 minutes. Will try it today and will update this.

Comment: thank you.   I honestly never thought about soaking the grains first before cooking them.  You just helped me move one step closer to cooking grains within 5-6 minutes.

Comment: your welcome.  Happy I helped !

Comment: Hi Nisha Judy, any way to store premoistend, but uncooked rice long term?  If you want to know more about what I'm working on, drop me a line at jonathan@sebandfrankie.com.  I'll be happy to tell you about all my odd grain cooking questions.

Comment: @Jonathan The reason why rice is storable long-term is that it is too low moisture for bacteria to survive in it. Premoistened rice is by definition not storeable long-term, it has to be treated like cooked food.

Comment: well i really dont understand abt premoistend rice. In india we use to soak cooked rice with water for a week in fridge. but the rice is only good to eat with yoghurt. I have to think and even chat with my grannies whether they did smtg like wat u say in old days

Answer (score -1):

Without abusing the laws of physics any more than you already are with a pressure cooker, I'm afraid not.

Comment: Hi buttlord, I'm okay with abusing the laws of physics, as long as they get people to eat more healthily.  I'm trying to create a device that will cook certain raw foods as fast as a microwave reheats precooked food.  Rice is one of my targets.